# Excel Conditional formatting if in list

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a list of values J1:J100 and another list of values E1:E75

If a cell in column J matches a cell in column E, I would like this cell to be highlighted.

Any ideas what formula to enter into the conditional formatting prompt for Excel? I'm not too sure of syntax for conditional formatting.

I've found this online:

http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=149496

And tried to tweak it but to little avail.

Answer (score 3):

If you highlight column J and use Conditional Formatting's "*Use formula to determine which cells to format*" with the following formula, it should work.

> =COUNTIF(E:E, J1)

This will count any cells in column J that match column E, then apply the formatting you choose.

Don't forget to set the formatting you want if the formula is true.